# Django. When should I use to_field?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to learn about this option. I've tried to find examples online and to learn when could this Foreign Key argument could be useful. Could anyone with a better understanding than me explain this to me? The docs write:

```
 The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.
```

... But, when should I use it?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: to_field can be used to relate a foreignkey filed.   ex: if you want to relate profile of a user with username, you can use to_field='username' instead of primarykey of the user.

Comment: Please search for something first, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730207/django-model-set-foreign-key-to-a-field-of-another-model